# How can I get KroneckerDelta to contract an index?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a sum like

```
f = Sum[x[i]^2, {i,1,Infinity}]
```

and I want to take a derivative of this with respect to one of the variables, e.g.

```
D[f, x[i]]
```

which returns

```
Sum[KroneckerDelta[i,p]x[p], {p,1,Infinity}]
```

and I would like this to contract to `x[i]`. Instead what I get on output is

```
UnitStep[-1 + i] x[i]
```

I can get what I want if I use

```
Refine[Sum[KroneckerDelta[i, j] x[j], {j, 1, Infinity}], 
       Element[i,PositiveIntegers]]
```

But if I have

```
g = Sum[x[p]^3,{p,1,Infinity}]
```

and calculate

```
Refine[D[g,x[i]], Element[i,PositiveIntegers]]
```

I get

```
Sum[3 KroneckerDelta[i,p]x[p]^2, {p,1,Infinity}]
```

and there seems no way to force the `KroneckerDelta` to collapse the sum to a single term!

Comment: Try: `Assuming[i ∈ PositiveIntegers, D[g, x[i]]]`

Comment: Thanks, that worked in my little example but not when there are multiple derivatives. For example D[x[i],x[j]]=KroneckerDelta[i,j], but if I use Assuming[i ∈ PositiveIntegers,D[x[i],x[j]] I get zero.